# Grouped and concatenate arrays in php

Tags: php

Here's my arrays, Is there a possible way to make the arrays group or concate? The expected output below.

```
[test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => one
                    [1] => two
                    [2] => three
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 2098
                    [2] => 2086
                )

        )
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
[test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => one, 2
                    [1] => two, 2098
                    [2] => three, 2086
                )
        )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that your nested arrays have the same number of elements:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: felix manzanas
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Grouped and concatenate arrays in php
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585692/grouped-and-concatenate-arrays-in-php
Tags: php

*/

$arr = [
    'test' => [
        ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        [2, 2098, 2086]
    ]
];

$output = ['test' => []];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr['test'][0]); ++$i) {
    $tempArr = [];
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr['test']); ++$j) {
        $tempArr[] = $arr['test'][$j][$i];
    }
    $output['test'][0][$i] = implode(', ', $tempArr);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Results in:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "one, 2"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "two, 2098"
      [2]=>
      string(11) "three, 2086"
    }
  }
}
```